# A Windows batch file to c:\*.pst and copy them to a network drive without files with a duplicate name overwriting each other

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, duplicates, xcopy

My end users have Outlook pst files scattered all over their c drive. I came up with this batch file to find them and copy them to the end user's M drive.

```
rem **************************************************
@echo off
if not exist m:\migration mkdir m:\migration
if not exist m:\migration\pst mkdir m:\migration\pst
c:
dir /b c:\*.pst /s > m:\migration\pathdata.txt

pause

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (m:\migration\pathdata.txt) do (copy "%%a" m:\migration\pst) 

pause
```

BUT this paltry solution can't handle if the files have the same name, which is to be expected (archive.pst)

I was hoping to use xcopy to copy them and create their directory structure on drive M, that way files with the same names wont overwrite each other. But I have failed.

Any ideas?  Thank you for helping me with this

Answer (score 2):

I used this blog for help please check this one. It will search files and then copy to network location

http://tshootissues.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

```
XCopy /-U c:\*.pst m:\migration\pst
```

The /U option will only copy files that already exist. The /-U should copy only those that do not already exist.

or

```
echo n|copy /-y c:\*.pst m:\migration\pst
```

source: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=537

Comment: thats good too but it isn't installed by default on systems running windows XP or older, but as long as it works :D

Comment: robocopy c:\ m:\pst *.pst /r: /s

I just lucked into this and gave it a try. I did not know robocopy was part of Windows 7 or the windows 2003 resource pack.

Thank you Joe DF!!!! I still might use that suggestion. You Rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is something you should observe with `dir /b c:\*.pst /s > m:\migration\pathdata.txt`
If you open your pathdata.txt or do `for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %a in (m:\migration\pathdata.txt) do @echo %i` you will notice you have paths like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\FILENAME.pst
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\FILENAME.pst
```

And so on, but note it is actually the same file. This happens because `dir /b c:\*.pst /s` will go through folder shortcuts therefore you will have a .txt file with lots of path names pointing to the same .pst and when you `xcopy` you will copy the same file multiple times.

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747723/making-a-for-batch-file-search-creates-an-infinite-loop-how-do-i-stop-it) which solves the problem then you can do the `robocopy` answer or modify it to your need.

Since you have multiple users and if your M drive is a network drive you could use `m:\migration\%username%\pst` to have it copied by user. That way if a user's pst have the same name as another user's pst you wont overwrite it and also you would be identifying them.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general caution that PST file may get vulnerable threat on network driver or server. This truth is also accepted by MVP and Microsoft. So, it can use only at local drive only to avoid any problematic situation.