# While searching for .pst files FOR keeps looping when it reaches a hidden shortcut folder

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, infinite-loop, filepath, shortcut

The following command creates an infinite loop which is not what I want since I am iterating through files and it needs to end sometime...

Here is what I have:

```
cd C:\
FOR /R %i IN (*.pst) do @echo %i
```

See what happens is that when it reaches AppData and finds a .pst (in AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook) there is a shortcut folder inside AppData\Local called "Application Data" which loops back to AppData\Local but keeps adding it's name to the address like so:

```
%AppData%\Local\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook\%filename%.pst
```

What could I add to my code to keep it from looping or much better to completely ignore shortcuts so that the loop ends when it finds all the files that I need?

-----------Edit-------------

This seems to do something similar:

```
dir /s /b *.pst
```

Comment: [This site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) has helped me with `for` loop questions with batch files before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out reparse points with `DIR /A-L`.

However, using `DIR /A-L /S` won't work also, because reparse point contents are not reparse points, so, try this:

Instead of `FOR` use:

```
FindFiles.bat *.pst c:\
```

Create a `FindFiles.bat` file with:

```
@ECHO OFF
:GetDirFiles %1=Wildcard %2=Path
FOR %%f IN ("%~f2\%~1") DO ECHO %%~ff
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%d IN ('DIR /B /AD-L "%~f2"') DO CALL :GetDirFiles %1 "%~2\%%d"
```

This will recursivelly get all directories which are not reparse points and echo items matching pattern for each directory.

Comment: Ok what I did was save all your code to a findfiles.bat. The first for is just returning me a dir /b \. and the second for is not returning me anything. I'm not quite certain, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If I add /s to ('dir /b "%~2\%~1"') I get through all shortcuts again.

Comment: Check edit. Ideia is doing "manual" `/S`, ignoring reparse points.

Comment: Edit just echoes File Not Found until I manually terminate the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I recommend you use `forfiles` which should be on your computer if your using windows 7. Type `forfiles /?` for more info. Try this:

```
forfiles /p "C:\" /s /m "*.pst" /c "cmd /c (Echo @path)"
```

That should work perfectly. Im looking in ways of doing this with a `for /r` loop. It probably involves a `dir` check in a `for /r /d`. Tell me if this works fine for you.

Mona